# ExpandableListView how to implement with ListView?

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I want to make a navigationDrawer which has layout something like this

```
-Home
 -Transaction
   -Cash
   -Bank
 -Summary
```

How to implement this? I have searched on Google, but what I have found is ExpandableListView, but it expands all the entries, but I want only transaction to be Expandable. Any idea on this?

Comment: Here Cash and Bank is subcategory of Transaction..

Comment: I have made a complete navigationBar with ListView and one with ExpandableListView but how to merge them?

Comment: Use Expandable listview in your drawer, and set child items only to your Transaction field.